# Vue - Moving Backgrounds With Mouse Position

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I new to vuejs!. I would like to move the background image when mouse position is moving around, how to do this in vuejs.

```js
const el = document.querySelector("#module");

el.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  el.style.backgroundPositionX = -e.offsetX + "px";
  el.style.backgroundPositionY = -e.offsetY + "px";
});
```

```css
.module {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1499162526249-f5b8b9ba9923?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=865bf5c0b77ceb22e88de9fd41c5a671);
  background-size: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="module" id="module">
  
</div>
```

Comment: so what's exactly your problem? For me it seems to work.

Comment: @patrick96 Hi, now the example that I provided is pure js, not vuejs

Answer (score 0):

Just add `@mousemove` to your div with link to method that will handle your behaviour. Also you can create reference to this element via `ref`. Sadly I can not create a block of code on tablet, but you can check out this answer [here](https://qna.habr.com/q/509436), that’s exactly what you need.